# How to prevent insertion in FormView?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-entities, formview, entitydatasource

I want to check my form before inserting to prevent insert duplicate ProductSerial in my data base.
so how can i check the txtProductSerial.text with my database and if it is duplicate I PREVENT INSERTION.
This are my codes

```
 protected void fvwSoldForm_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    e.Values["DateX"] = DateTime.Now;
    e.Values["IsDeleted"] = false;
    e.Values["Confirmed"] = false;
    var solded = db.SoldedByResellers.ToList();
    solded = solded.Where(p => p.ProductSerial == NumericSerial.Text).ToList();
    if (solded.Count > 0)
        Alert("Please Change the serial code, This code Used before");
//Here WHAT EVER I DO THE INSERTING GOES ON. I WANT TO STOP INSERTING HERE



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancel the operation, set:

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

This will prevent the insert from happening.  See the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formviewinserteventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example.